# eclipse scala plugin, scala project type missing

Tags: eclipse-plugin

After installing the scala eclipse plugin on helios the scala project type is missing, there is no scala options in the preferences and no other indication that installation has worked. Then when I check 'what is already installed' in the install new software window I can see that the plugin is there....

I can replicate the same problem across several machines in the office however I'm able to install on my own machine at home without a problem....

anyone got any ideas/tips on how to troubleshoot this ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like not everything was installed properly.

Before figuring out what is going on, try answering these questions:

1. In preferences, look for JDT Weaving.  Is it enabled?
2. Any errors in your error log?
3. What version Eclipse are you running?
4. For your office machines is Eclipse installed in a read-only directory or C:\Program Files?

Comment: thanks for the answering - JDT weaving is enabled, I'm using Helios and the office machine have write permissions to program files... there's a bunch of erros in the logs but nothing that looks related to the scala plugin

Comment: Try it again with the *current* release, Indigo SR2.